Showing that the set of strictly Levi pseudoconvex boundary points of $C^2$ domain is not empty.
This question comes from R. Michael Range's Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables, exercise 2.2.14.a: Let $D$ be a relatively compact domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $C^2$ boundary. Show that the set of strictly Levi pseudoconvex boundary points of $D$ is nonempty.
The hint to the question says to fix $a \in D$ and look at some point $P \in bD$ at maximal distance from $a$.
Ideas/what I've tried: I am looking at a point $P \in bD$ at maximal distance away from $a$, i.e. this point should lie on the boundary of some ball $B(a; \tilde{r})$ where $\tilde{r} = \inf r$ such that $bB(a; r) \cap bD = \emptyset$. The ball $B(a; \tilde{r})$ is strictly Levi pseudoconvex at every boundary point, and I want to use this fact to show that the $C^2$ defining function for $D$ near $P$ satisfies the strict Levi condition at $P$. Intuitively, I think this makes sense; the boundary of $D$ should "curve away" from the boundary of the ball near $P$, but this seems to impose a condition on the real Hessian of the defining function near $P$, rather than the Levi form.
Is this a good line of argumentation, and if so, how do I connect my geometric intuition back to the analytic objects I am working with/how do I connect the real Hessian with the Levi form?

I believe I have come to a solution, which is below in case anyone has a similar question in the future. If you believe my solution is incorrect, please comment so below.
We let $D \subset\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ have $C^2$ boundary, and let $a \in D$. Choose $P \in bD$ of maximal distance from $a$, i.e. an element of $bB(a; \tilde{r}) \cap bD$ where $\tilde{r} = \inf\{r: bB(a; r) \cap bD = \emptyset\}$. Such a $P$ must exist since $bD$ is compact in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Clearly $D \subseteq B(a; \tilde{r})$ and $B(a; \tilde{r})$ is not only strictly Levi pseudoconvex at $P \in bB(a; \tilde{r})$, but also strictly convex at $P$ in standard coordinates on $\mathbb{C}^n$. We also have (by construction) that $T_P(b D) = T_P(bB(a; \tilde{r})$. Let $\rho_1, \rho_2 \in C^2(U)$ be defining functions for $D$ and $B(a; \tilde{r})$ respectively in a (wlog the same) neighborhood $U$ of $P$. Clearly $\rho_1(P) = \rho_2(P) = 0$. We claim that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j, k = 1}^{2 n} \frac{\partial^2 \rho_2}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}(P) \xi_k \xi_j \leq \sum_{j, k = 1}^{2 n} \frac{\partial^2 \rho_1}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}(P) \xi_k \xi_j
\end{equation*}
for all $\xi \in T_P(bD)$, i.e. the (real) Hessian of $\rho_2$ bounds the Hessian of $\rho_1$ below. Indeed, suppose to the contrary that there is some $\xi \in T_P(b D)$ such that $\text{Hess}_P(\rho_1; \xi) < \text{Hess}_P(\rho_2; \xi)$. Then $\partial^2 \rho_1/\partial \xi^2 < \partial^2 \rho_2/\partial \xi^2$ at $P$ and thus there is a neighborhood $V \subseteq U$ of $P$ such that $\rho_1(P + \lambda \xi) < \rho_2(P + \lambda \xi)$ for all $\lambda \neq 0$ such that $P + \lambda \xi \in V$. But by continuity of $\rho_1, \rho_2$ there must be a potentially smaller neighborhood $V' \subseteq V$ of the line $P + \lambda \xi$ minus the point $P$ on which $\rho_1 < \rho_2$, and in particular there must be a boundary point $\zeta \in bB(a; \tilde{r})$ with $\rho_1(\zeta) < \rho_2(\zeta)$, a contradiction since $D \subseteq B(a; \tilde{r})$. Thus we have $\text{Hess}_P(\rho_1; \xi) \geq \text{Hess}_P(\rho_2; \xi)$ for all $\xi \in T_P(b D)$, and since $\text{Hess}_P(\rho_2; \xi) > 0$ for all $\xi \neq 0$ in $T_P(b D)$ we have the same for $\text{Hess}_P(\rho_1; \xi)$. It then follows from either theorem [2.2.17] or the proof of lemma [2.2.10] that $D$ is strictly Levi pseudoconvex at $P$ (the proof of the aforementioned lemma gives the relation between the real Hessian of $\rho_1$ and its Levi form).
